# Make a pop up message if about to call area codes excluding specified

Tags: macrodroid

So I wanted a pop up message/dialog box  to appear whenever I dial/call number with prefixes excluded from my list.

To clarify, there are two codes. One is the country code and the other is the network code. For instance, country code is `+63` and network (company) code is `945`. Country code is only one. While network code reaches like a hundred. I want a pop up message to appear when the prefix is other than `+63945*`, `+63917*`, `+63906*`, and 20+ other numbers. In other words, there would be no pop up when the prefixes I set are being dialled/called while every other number would prompt a pop up message.

I used this macro but all the numbers I dial seem to activate the dialog box. The macro is working but there seems to be an error somewhere.

<sub>(Click to enlarge the images)</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working macro with explanation in comments

<sub>(Click to enlarge)</sub>

[image]

**Note**

1. Log events write to the log which can be accessed from the home screen of the app and are useful to check errors.
2. Screenshot shows the local variable value, which is also useful in troubleshooting.
3. Your macro had matching condition `excludes` which is wrong, it needs to be `!=` (not equal to).
4. In the Text Manipulation action, the output should be saved to the variable A

Edit : The answer above is in response to the [previous version](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/228569/4) of the question